# Why is tessdata throwing Exceptions?

Tags: tesseract, tess4j

All is happening on **MAC** in SpringBoot WAR file deployed in Tomcat:

I have tesseract 4.1.0 installed (via brew on Mac).

For Tessdata - OCR on Mac

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.tess4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>tess4j</artifactId>
        <version>4.4.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

I also updated SpringBoot today to:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
```

---

Now, when I try to run the OCR logic in tessdata (Service method in SpringBoot), I am first getting this error (on the mac):

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;
```

Then, if I try to OCR the Spanish png file again, I get this result:

```
"Could not initialize class net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI"
```

The Tessdata code where the crash occurs seems to be:

```
public String doOCR(BufferedImage var1) throws TesseractException {
    return this.doOCR((BufferedImage)var1, (Rectangle)null);
```

I've seen postings here about this problem, but all the ones I've seen are for Windows. I also tried to load the dependency for jna just in case, but that made no difference.

Has anyone faced and fixed this issue?

***The problem appears to be with the tess4j 4.4.0. If I back it out to the last version, then things work again.***

Would really appreciate some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

It seems your application is loading an old JNA version. `com.sun.jna.Native.load` is new in JNA 5.x.x. So make sure you use the latest JNA version.

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jna-users/VKbCGUcotkg

Comment: Thanks very much! That definitely fixed it. I can't believe I didn't use the current jna version when trying to fix this. It's also a bit confusing why this jna dependency was needed now and not in the last tess4j version. But, all is good now. Thanks again.