# How to make doOCR work without any issue using Java opencv

Tags: java, opencv, ocr, tesseract

Getting an error while executing doOCR method.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:85)
```

I have added `tess4j.4.4.0.jar` and `jna - 5.3.1.jar`

I have changed the JNA and JNA platform

```
Tesseract ocr = new Tesseract();
ocr.setDatapath("C:\\Users\\<username>\\Desktop\\<foldername>\\Tessdata");

String aasds = ocr.doOCR(new File("C:/Users/<username>/Desktop/<foldername>/XP5gray.jpg"));
System.out.println(aasds);
```

Please find the below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.sun.jna.Native.load(Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Class;)Lcom/sun/jna/Library;
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.util.LoadLibs.getTessAPIInstance(LoadLibs.java:85)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.TessAPI.`enter code here`clinit(TessAPI.java:42)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.init(Tesseract.java:427)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:223)
    at net.sourceforge.tess4j.Tesseract.doOCR(Tesseract.java:195)
    at com.xp8.util.TessDemo.main(TessDemo.java:86)
```

Comment: Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57379212/why-is-tessdata-throwing-exceptions/57383042#57383042. It appears you're loading an old JNA version.

Comment: I am using latest JNA version - 5.3.1, still the problem persists

Answer (score 0):

It could be a case of dependency conflicts. Follow these articles to resolve it.

https://dzone.com/articles/solving-dependency-conflicts-in-maven
https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html

Comment: - Thanks for the above suggestion.